# Jquery Mobile footer links/buttons not working after scroll.(Google Chrome, Android 4.2.1)

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, mobile

I am trying to build a page with jquerymobile, and i have a fixed footer.
The problem i have is that after i've scrolled down on my browser, the link is not working.
When i scroll up, it is working again.

this is the code im using

```
    <div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="true" data-fullscreen="true" >
    <a href="#cards" data-icon="arrow-u" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Card functions</a>
</div>
```

I am using a clean install of jquerymobile, with latest jquery-ui.
CSS is default..

i did find a similar question, but this was outdated and the fix didnt work .

Answer (score 0):

Try a navbar inside your footer, this fixed the same problem for me:

```
<div data-role="footer">
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
<p style="text-align:center;">I'm the footer</p>
```

Source: [jQuery mobile demo](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/navbar/)

Its a known issue: [jQuery mobile @ github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3869)